# Django Crispy form define a class for the form field

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using Django crispy form to design the html for my forms .

I have two radio button which is designed like

```
Div(InlineRadios('special_question'), css_class="tr-form-r5 "),
```

I want to define the same class name for both Yes and no options radio buttons .

But not able to figure out how to do that .

I tried like .

`InlineRadios('...', css_class="xxx")`

But it does not work .

Please suggest me what might I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work?".  Do you mean you can't see those classes applied to the HTML when viewing it in your browsers inspector?  The classes are applied to the HTML, but the styles don't show up? ...

Comment: the class does not appearing in the firebug

Comment: and you've got `css_class` attributes working on other fields?  You should post the entire form as you have it defined in the code the you're using (if it's not proprietary).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to resolve this problem using CSS.

For your form class:

```
class ConfirmationForm (forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        # set form class is well documented
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-special' 

        super(ConfirmationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then add some a CSS rule:

```
.form-special input[type="radio"] {
    /* whatever you want */
}
```

You can even find this way more neat and less cumbersome.